How do I shade the left-hand side of the cells in a tikz matrix?
I have a color scheme I want to use in a tikz matrix.  I can already shade the whole cell, but I'd like to shade only a portion of the left of each cell, making sure the font is in front of a white background.  Here's an illustration of the idea:

Question: How do I shade the left-hand side of the cells in a tikz matrix?
Here's a minimum working example (I need to use xelatex to compile so it compiles the Chinese correctly):
\documentclass[crop,margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{HSK1}{HTML}{F9A94A}
\definecolor{HSK2}{HTML}{3999A7}
\definecolor{HSK3}{HTML}{ED6E07}
\definecolor{HSK4}{HTML}{B81D25}
\definecolor{HSK5}{HTML}{253E77}
\definecolor{HSK6}{HTML}{673568}
\definecolor{HSK7}{HTML}{AECFB7}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK SC} % Set your primary font

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pagecolor{black}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{vocabulary matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=0.2cm, row sep=0.2cm,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum height=1cm,
      anchor=center,
      text width=2cm,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt,
      rounded corners,
      thick
    },
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm
}

\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont

\matrix[vocabulary matrix] {
|[fill=HSK1]| 爱 &
|[fill=HSK2]| 安 &
|[fill=HSK3]| 阿 &
|[fill=HSK4]| 阿 &
|[fill=HSK5]| 阿 &
|[fill=HSK6]| 阿 &
|[fill=HSK7]| 阿 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


The number of people who are potentially able to help you, would be larger if you simplify your example so one does not need special fonts etc.

You can do this with a path picture.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{mynode/.style={
    draw, minimum height=1cm, anchor=center, text width=2cm, 
    align=center, inner sep=0pt, rounded corners, thick, 
    path picture={
        \fill[#1, sharp corners](path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle ([xshift=3mm]path picture bounding box.north west);
    }
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode=blue] at (0,0){A};
\node[mynode=orange] at (3,0){B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Adapting this to your example, the nodes must be filled white:

\documentclass[crop,margin=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{HSK1}{HTML}{F9A94A}
\definecolor{HSK2}{HTML}{3999A7}
\definecolor{HSK3}{HTML}{ED6E07}
\definecolor{HSK4}{HTML}{B81D25}
\definecolor{HSK5}{HTML}{253E77}
\definecolor{HSK6}{HTML}{673568}
\definecolor{HSK7}{HTML}{AECFB7}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
%\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK SC} % Set your primary font

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\pagecolor{black}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{vocabulary matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=0.2cm, row sep=0.2cm
  },
  square matrix/.default=1.2cm,
  mynode/.style={
    draw, minimum height=1cm, anchor=center, text width=2cm, 
    align=center, inner sep=0pt, rounded corners, thick, fill=white,
    path picture={
        \fill[#1, sharp corners](path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle ([xshift=3mm]path picture bounding box.north west);
    }
}
}

\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont

\matrix[vocabulary matrix] {
|[mynode=HSK1]| 爱 &
|[mynode=HSK2]| 安 &
|[mynode=HSK3]| 阿 &
|[mynode=HSK4]| 阿 &
|[mynode=HSK5]| 阿 &
|[mynode=HSK6]| 阿 &
|[mynode=HSK7]| 阿 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


The answer using path picture by @Sandy is well-fitted for this case. Here I give another solution using like-node pic inside a matrix of pics. It may helpful for more complicated tasks. Make sure that you are compiled with XeLaTeX.


% compile with XeLaTeX
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{Noto Sans CJK SC} % Set your primary font
\def\a{2} \def\b{1}
\tikzset{c/.style={draw, minimum height=\b cm, anchor=center, text width=\a cm, align=center, inner sep=0pt, rounded corners, thick}} 
\tikzset{pics/mybox/.style args=
    {marking color=#1, text=#2}{code={%
\begin{scope}
\clip[rounded corners] (-\a/2,-\b/2) rectangle (\a/2,\b/2);  ;
\fill[#1] (-\a/2,-\b/2) rectangle +(.3,\b);           
\end{scope}
\path (0,0) node[c] {#2};   
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path 
(0,0)  pic (A) {mybox={marking color=blue, text=愛}}
(3,0)  pic (B) {mybox={marking color=red, text=爱}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pagecolor{black!20}
\definecolor{HSK1}{HTML}{F9A94A}
\definecolor{HSK2}{HTML}{3999A7}
\definecolor{HSK3}{HTML}{ED6E07}
\definecolor{HSK4}{HTML}{B81D25}
\definecolor{HSK5}{HTML}{253E77}
\definecolor{HSK6}{HTML}{673568}
\definecolor{HSK7}{HTML}{AECFB7}

\tikzset{vocabulary matrix/.style={
    column sep=0.2cm, row sep=0.2cm
  }}
\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont

\matrix[vocabulary matrix] {
\pic{mybox={marking color=HSK1, text=明}}; &
\pic{mybox={marking color=HSK2, text=月}}; &
\pic{mybox={marking color=HSK3, text=幾}}; &
\pic{mybox={marking color=HSK4, text=時}}; &
\pic{mybox={marking color=HSK5, text=有}}; &\\
\pic{mybox={marking color=HSK6, text=把}}; &
\pic{mybox={marking color=HSK7, text=酒}}; &
\pic{mybox={marking color=HSK6, text=問}}; &
\pic{mybox={marking color=HSK7, text=青}}; &
\pic{mybox={marking color=HSK6, text=天}};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

